# How to use useEffect with forwardRef in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

This is my code:

```js
import React from 'react';

type shapeTable = {
  data: string[][];
  onMount?: (tableWidth: string) => void;
};

 type Ref = HTMLTableElement;

 const Table = React.forwardRef<Ref, shapeTable>(({ data, onMount }, ref) => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log('ref = ', ref);
    if (ref) {
      console.log('ref.current = ', ref.current);
    }
    // const $table = ref.current;
    // if (ref && onMount) {
    //   const tableWidth:string = window.getComputedStyle($table).getPropertyValue("width");
    //   onMount(tableWidth);
    // }
  });
  return data.length ? (
    <table ref={ref}>
      <tbody>
        {data.slice(1).map(tr => (
          <tr>
            {tr.map(item => (
              <td>{item}</td>
            ))}
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  ) : null;
});
```

## Error

It fails on ref.current

It seems to struggle with ref.current.

I'm struggling to force the Ref to be only "HTMLTableElement".

Any suggestions, thanks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the working example

```js
const { useState, useRef, createRef, forwardRef, useEffect } = React;

const Table = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('ref: ', ref && ref.current);
  }, [ref])

  return <table ref={ref}>
    {props.children}
  </table>
})


const App = () => {
  const ref = useRef();

  return <Table ref={ref}>
    <tbody></tbody>
  </Table>
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

**--Edit**

Quite a horrifying definition when you look at resolved type of ref in intellisense

```js
((instance: HTMLTableElement | null) => void) | React.MutableRefObject<HTMLTableElement | null> | null
```

That means you have to check if `ref` is defined and `ref` is not a `function`

And if `ref.current` is also defined, just to keep `&&` going

...or just cast to any and don't bother.

Up to you

```js
const Table = React.forwardRef<HTMLTableElement >((props, ref) => {

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if(ref && typeof ref !== "function" && ref.current) {

      console.log('ref: ', ref.current);
      // ref.current.getBoundingClientRect()
    }

  }, [ref])

  return <table ref={ref}>
    {props.children}
  </table>
})
```

Comment: Thanks but I need it in typescript. It is typescript that is failing

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: oh my god. That is such a hidden problem. Thankyou so much. That solved it.